# Serialization of 'class@anonymous' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I want create anonymous class extend a other class, because i want modify a few method and add a few property to class as follow:

```php
$this->repo = new class ($userExport) extends AdsDataSponsorRepository{
    protected $userExport;

    public function __construct($userExport)
    {
        $this->userExport = $userExport;
    }

    public function getFilterQuery($filter = [], $timeRange = null)
    {
        if (isset($filter[TIME_RANGE])) {
            $query = $this->getQueryWithRangeTime($filter[TIME_RANGE]);
            \App\Helpers::filterFromParams($filter, $query, [], true);
        } else if ($timeRange !== null) {
            $query = $this->getQueryWithRangeTime($timeRange);
            \App\Helpers::filterFromParams($filter, $query, [], true);
        } else {
            $query = $this->modelView();
            \App\Helpers::filterFromParams($filter, $query,
                ['num_success', 'num_sent', 'num_fail', 'total_money', 'rate_success'], true);
        }

        \App\Helpers::customFilterRunningTime($filter, $query);

        if($this->userExport == null){
            $this->userExport = auth()->user();
        }

        if (!$this->userExport->hasRole(ROLE_IS_ADMIN)) {
            $query->where(function ($q) {
                $q->where("agency_id", auth()->id())->orWhere('advertiser_id', auth()->id());
            });
        }
        return $query;
    }
};
```

so, when i run this class in queue got 1 errors again:

```
    "message": "Serialization of 'class@anonymous' is not allowed",
```

class run without queue OK, but cannot run with queue. Can you help me run them with queue or other solve instead anonymouse class can modify method or insert new property. Thanks.

Comment: it can't be serialized, define a class and get an instance of that to use

Comment: but i want use it one time, and not use again. So what other way?

Comment: then only use it once, but you still need to define a class ... anonymous classes can not be serialized

Comment: Can you try this https://markbakeruk.net/2018/06/25/using-php-anonymous-classes-as-package-private-classes/